# How to improve the positioning code?

Tags: html, css, css-position, smartphone

The following is my code for positioning text over image. The requirements are:

1. Image should be adapt to screen automatically. Even on smart phone, the image should be displayed completely. Only showing part of the image is not allowed.
2. Text should be accurately positioned anywhere I wish.

```css
.txtimg{
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.txtimg img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bl, .tl, .br,
.tr{
  margin: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
}

.bl{
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.tl{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.br{
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.tr{
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="txtimg">
  
  <img src="http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg">
  
  <p class="bl">(text to appear at the bottom left of the image)</p>
  <p class="tr"> (text to appear at the top right of the image)</p>

</div>
```

However, the bottom left text is hide from fully displayed on my **firefox** browser.
[image]

It is wired that the code snippet runs pretty well in **stackoverflow** by clicking the `Run Code Snippet` below.

I don't know why. Anywhere I found a solution: change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:visible`. The problem will disappear.

Anyone advice?

Comment: many types of smart phone has different browsers with all kinds of compatibility issues. but if you are able to connect to device and use chrome inspect element will be a lot easy to debug. remoute debugging, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. In another `CSS` class, I have already include the "overflow:hidden" line. So, I remove the corresponding line in class `txtimg`.

Comment: Okay, so it explain why i couldn't reproduce the issue. Good you found!

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem on this specific code, but i know the problem. Simply add a vertical-align on the image.

```
.txtimg img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This also work like this :

```
.txtimg img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Both does not work for me. Could you explain the reason? Why this work?

Comment: Because img is an inline-block element, which can be verticaly aligned. The default state is "baseline", and result in a blank space under the image (dunno why). It can be solved by specifying a new vertical-align, or remove the formating context by make it a block